# App is crashing because of a zombie when switching tabs

Tags: ios, swift, nszombie

I have an app with a TabBarNavigationController and a NavigationController.
The views of the navigation Controller are

`HomeViewController`

`CharacterViewController`

`FinalViewController`

I have a function in `CharacterViewController` and `FinalViewController` so that if the user tap the tab bar item of the navigation controller it shows the `HomeViewController`:

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0{
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
    }
}
```

When the user is in `CharacterViewController` or in `FinalViewController` and goes to the other tab then taps again the Navigation Controller tab the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` gets called and the user is in `HomeViewController`.

Everything until this point works, the problem is when at this point I tap the other tab from the tab bar, the app crashes.
In the logs it shows me

```
2015-09-06 14:02:24.120 PIBA[32338:510545] *** -[PIBA.CharacterViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x79e88320
```

If I use a breakpoint it shows

```
0x8a217f <+783>:  jmp    0x8a2288
```

(Wich doesnt helps me)

So I searched for NS Zombies and the test showed that in the line:

```
 self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
```

An object is being released

But what object? and how can I retain it?

Comment: Are you using `unowned` anywhere?

Comment: No, im not using it @jtbandes